Manifest V3 chrome extension that authenticates to firebase with user's google account
I'm trying to build manifest V3 chrome extension with React js that should connect to firestore and perform CRUD tasks. The user of the extension should sign In with his existing gmail account. Google's CSP policy makes my life hard by preventing loading scripts from external sources and preventing the user from opening pop-up windows (for signInWithPopup method) . I've seen many people online struggling with this.
Can anybody explain me step-by-step how can I implement the authentication?
The official documentation of firebase says that I should put google's sign-in pop up window in I-frame:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/chrome-extension, but unfortunately, I could not make it work.
Is there anybody here who implemented this successfully, and can explain me step-by-step how can I make this work?

Go to the Firebase console . Enable the Google Sign-In method in the authentication tab.
Initialize Firebase in your extension**: Install Firebase in your project (npm install firebase) and initialize it with your Firebase project's credentials.
Handle the sign-in process*: Since you can't open a pop-up window due to CSP restrictions, you'll need to use the firebase.auth().currentUser method to check if a user is already signed in. If not, you can use the firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider) method to redirect the user to the sign-in page.
Handle the sign-in redirect**: In your index.html file, you can use a fullpage iframe to handle the sign-in redirect. Make sure to set the src attribute to the URL of your extension's popup page.
Handle the sign-in on the popup page**: On your popup page, you can use the firebase.auth().getRedirectResult() method to get the sign-in result. If the sign-in is successful, you can then close the popup page and return the user to your extension.
